# how to consume two JAX-RS Post methods with http

Tags: html, http, jax-rs

I create a web service like below:

```
@ApplicationPath("/FirstTest")
@Path("/")
public class RSmethod {
    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String createCustomer(@FormParam("name") String name,
                                 @FormParam("address") String address,
                                 @FormParam("phone-number") String phoneNumber) {
        return name+" "+address+" "+phoneNumber;
    }
```

And I write a html page like below to access it.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/RSexample/FirstTest/" method="post" >
 Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
  phone: <input type="text" name="phone-number" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I add another Post method then how to write html code to access this one? Thx.

```
  @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String createCustomer1(@FormParam("name") String name,
                                 @FormParam("address") String address,
                                 @FormParam("phone-number") String phoneNumber) {
        return "This is test 2";
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood according to your question
add   @Path annotation to differentiate between these to methods.

e.g. 1)   `@Path("customers")`

```
    @Path("customers")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String createCustomer1(@FormParam("name") String name,
                                 @FormParam("address") String address,
                                 @FormParam("phone-number") String phoneNumber) {
        return "This is test 2";
     }
```